# Why use 'speedily' rather than 'quickly'?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the last few years, I have become aware of a few people using the word 'speedily', for example 'to speedily find'. 
My initial reaction has always been to wonder why they didn't use the word 'quickly' instead of what seems to be a contrived word of 'speedily'.
Am I wrong to find this word jarring and contrived?

Comment: See if this helps - https://wikidiff.com/speedily/quickly

Comment: Why use any word at all?  You need to post examples of what you don't like.

Comment: Why do you say *initial*; couldn't you have just said *first*? It boasts fewer syllables and more phonetic spelling. Why do you say *contrived*, twice? Isn't that just a 50-cent way of saying *forced*? If language use is a constant war to economize vocabulary, why indeed say *speedily*, I agree. Double-plus-ungood.

Comment: Who says language use is a constant war to economize vocabulary. Sounds positively poisonous that. It all depends on what one is writing or saying. You wanna tell the Bard that?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a legitimate word.  I don't find it jarring, and if contrived, it was contrived hundreds of years ago.  It even appears in the King James version of the Bible:

> "Then they *speedily* took down every man his sack to the ground, and
>   opened every man his sack."

-Genesis 44:11

> "And David said in his heart, I shall now perish one day by the hand
>   of Saul: there is nothing better for me than that I should *speedily*
>   escape into the land of the Philistines; and Saul shall despair of me,
>   to seek me any more in any coast of Israel: so shall I escape out of
>   his hand."

-1 Samuel 27:1

I could go on, but "speedily" appears in the bible 20 times.

Incidentally, by comparison, "quickly" appears 38 times, but I don't see how "speedily" being used half as often ⁠— a bit more than half, actually ⁠— makes it jarring or contrived.  Perhaps if it were "velocitously," a word not found in any dictionary I know of, certainly not Merriam-Webster or OED, but nonetheless appears quite contrivedly and jarringly in a number of novels and other published works, like when Rosenblitt writing on modernism and the classics wrote:

> "But whether I'm wrong or I'm right, if you haven't yet met my friend
>   Timoleon, please do yourselves the honour of *velocitously* visiting a
>   good library..."